# Is there anyway to reduce the amount of ram in a system using software?

Tags: reactjs, windows, testing, web-applications, mern

I am a beginner at coding and working on a web application. I am currently working on a desktop with 16GB of DDR4 memory. However, potential clients in the future would be using laptops and most likely have only 8GB of ram that would potentially have a slower clock speed. While I could turn off my computer and take out a stick of memory for testing, I was wondering if there was a software based solution in windows that would allow me to temporarily shut off a stick of memory or limit the amount that is allowed to be used so that I could run some tests. If anyone knows how to do this I would greatly appreciate any help. If it helps to know, my development environment is VS Code and I am using the MERN stack (react in the front end).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best if you use some Virtual Machine software to create a machine with your desired spec. Using some software like this: https://superuser.com/questions/1263090/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-memory-usage-of-a-particular-process-on-windows for example requires some more configurations and controls compared to VM. You can use https://www.virtualbox.org/, it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Your OS by default takes the RAM it's given when booting up. It's nearly impossible to switch off RAM midusage at least in Windows. Memory management is something that's not allowed to be edited by external softwares but only by the operating system at least to my knowledge it is. You can use a virtual machine to test your software as an ideal solution but you can't lower the ram usage of the OS you're running now.